# AdMob Unity 5 2016

Tags: c#, unity3d, admob

Надо внедрить межстраничную рекламу AdMob в Unity 5. Смотрим [официальный мануал](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/games#unity) гугла, качаем, устанавливаем плагин. В нужном нам скрипте ставим

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
```

Ну и пишем предлагаемый код запроса межстраничника

```
private void RequestInterstitial()
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "Пишем сюда наш пробный айди, тоже с руководства гугла";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
    InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
    // Create an empty ad request.
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    // Load the interstitial with the request.
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
}
```

До этого момента всё было хорошо, а вот далее нам предлагается показать рекламу, создав при этом следующий метод, допустим по окончании игры.

```
private void GameOver()
{
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
        interstitial.Show();
    }
}
```

А вот тут начинаются проблемы - во первых подчёркивает красным слово `interstitial`, так как инициализировали мы его в `private void RequestInterstitial()`, а использовать пытаемся в `private void GameOver()`.

Очевидным решением проблемы для меня явилось объявление в главном методе

```
 InterstitialAd interstitial;
```

Подчёркивать перестало. Но - не работает. Причем, если в метод `GameOver()` написать что то другое, например, `SceneManager.LoadScene(0);` , оно успешно бросает тебя на первый уровень. А реклама не появляется, продолжает крутиться тот метод, с которого мы ссылались на `GameOver`, т.е. игра идёт дальше.

Добавлено для **Алексея Шиманского**:

@Алексей, я крайне вам благодарен за труды, но я, вообщем и целом так и делал сначала. Проблема то вот в чем - не идет ничего! Поэтому и пустился на всякие ухищрения с объединением методов. Даже специально создал новенький, чистый проект, импортировал туда этот плагин с гугла официальный, сделал по вашему - но толку нет. Вообще. Проект компилируется но реклама не выводится, хотя условия простые - просто UI кнопку нажать для GameOver. Вообщем код и несколько картинок. Обратите внимание на предупреждения на картинках, в нижней строке Unity. Может в них дело.

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;


public class ads: MonoBehaviour {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial; //Жалуется на нее

    void Start() {
        RequestInterstitial();


    }
    private void RequestInterstitial() {#
        if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";#
        elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";#
        else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";#
        endif

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }
    public void knopkaUI() {
        GameOver();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {


    }
    private void GameOver() {
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Картинки для наглядности 
[1](http://savepic.net/8241054.htm) 
[2](http://savepic.net/8226718.htm)
[3](http://savepic.net/8219550.htm)
[4](http://savepic.net/8224670.htm)
Саму рекламу разумеется тестировал на телефоне со включенным вайфай. Ждал минутку, пока возможно, загружается реклама, но безрезультатно - кнопку нажимается, но реклама не появляется. Идентификатор пользователя AdMob взял с примеров гугла, когда делал приложение в Android Studio по нему прилетала пробная реклама.

Comment: Эээ... А вы знаете, чем поле класса отличается от локальной переменной?

Comment: @VladD Ориентировочно, да.
Поле класса это переменная которая объявлена в классе, вида
`private Topori topor1;`, переменная топор1, которая член типа Топоры.
Локальная переменная представляет числовое или строковое значение или объект класса. Должна быть явно инициализирована в коде до появления любого оператора, в котором используются их значения.
Но это только слова, в голове как то пока не уложилось, как именно применять это по отношению к AdMob

Comment: Окей. Теперь подумайте о том, чем у вас является `interstitial`.

Comment: @VladD Вероятно, полем класса. Изначально она там и была только объявлена. Но такой вариант подчеркивает. В чем ошибка то?

Comment: Если вы запустите программу на компиляцию, обычно компилятор сообщает вам ошибку в текстовом виде. Это раз. Кроме того, подумайте, чем является `interstitial` в `RequestInterstitial`.

Comment: @VladD Да всё достаточно стандартно, 
Error CS0103 The name 'interstitial' does not exist in the current context 
А `interstitial` в `RequestInterstitial ` является локальной переменной. Дак а в чем проблема то?

Comment: @VladD Попробовал поместить всё это в один метод.Подчёркивание исчезло, но всё равно ничего не происходит, программа идет дальше.

Comment: Например, в том, что вы его создаёте и записываете с локальную переменную. А каким образом он при этом окажется в поле с тем же именем?

Comment: Если вы смогли добиться компилируемости, уже лучше. Теперь просто оттрассируйте в отладчике.

Comment: @VladD Я смог добиться компилируемости тем что объединил два метода, т.е. внаглую нарушил инструкцию гугла, и мне это совершенно не нравится. По трассировке тоже всё сложно - это реклама, она не запускается в самом Юнити, а на телефоне не видно консоли. Я не могу понять, почему не работает то что есть на официальной странице гугла? Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Не, вы должны найти, как именно подключить отладчик. Вам нужна не консоль, а отладка на телефоне (или на эмуляторе). Без отладки никто не скажет вам, что происходит на самом деле.

Comment: Окай..... вы объявили `private InterstitialAd _interstitial;`, а на кой ляд вы в методе `RequestInterstitial` пишите `InterstitialAd interstitial =  ...` ? Вы создали внутреннюю переменную......которая не относится к внешней...........`adLoadedPtr` видимо тоже не объявили или не присвоили начальное значение...где-нибудь перетерли

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Просто копирую как написано на офф сайте и добавляю то что говорите вы. Меня это и смущает, если сайт расчитан на мою компетентность, зачем в самом методе писать то что не видно из другого метода?   А что именно в методе написать? `interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);` ?
Просто куда то надо же `adUnitId` , это единственное место куда его можно поставить. Или нет?

Comment: @Dmitrii ну так и пишите `interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);`, а не `InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);` ......разница то есть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Проверил, действительно, всё работает. Вопрос в следующем - пример из офф.сайта действительно некорректен? Или в каких то случаях он заработает в неизменном виде?

Comment: @Dmitrii на самом деле он корректен.........просто, допустим, вы используете `interstitial` только в одном методе `RequestInterstitial()`... тогда достаточно того, что в доках........а если в стопицот методах, то подразумевается, что вы вынесите поле `interstitial` в класс, и уже в `RequestInterstitial` не будете писать `InterstitialAd interstitial = ...` .... потому что доки не будут же вам еще основы программирования рассказывать))) Как мне кажется .......... на всякий добавил прям эту строку в ответ в код. Хотя вы уже итак все поняли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В комментариях @VlaD вам намекнул, в чем, скорее всего проблема:

вы объявляете переменную `interstitial` с типом `InterstitialAd` в методе `RequestInterstitial` и там же её и инициализируете. Переменная, объявленная внутри какого-либо метода, живет только внутри него. Как только метод отрабатывает - переменная умирает, а значит в других методах к ней обратиться нельзя. Это основы не столько юнити, сколько программирования в целом.

Почему гугл написал так, а не иначе? Скорее всего потому, что он рассчитывает на вашу компетентность и что вы знаете эти самые основы и поэтому ему нет нужды разжевывать почему в одном примере переменная объявлена и инициализирована, а в другом якобы её же и используют.

выхода минимум два:

**Первый:** объявить переменную в самом классе и уже только тогда использовать её в различных методах:

```
class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    void Start(){
        // инициализируем interstitial;
        RequestInterstitial();
    }

    // здесь метод инициализации
    private void RequestInterstitial() {
         ...
         ...
         // InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId); <--- уже неправильно!
         interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId); 
         ...
    }

    private void GameOver() {
        // здесь interstitial доступна, т.к. видна внутри класса всем методам
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
           interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Второй:**

Есть на одном ресурсе, под названием *GitHub* уже готовый плагин для Юнити. Называется *admob-unity-plugin* и находится [здесь](https://github.com/guillermocalvo/admob-unity-plugin/tree/master/Releases) вместе с [доками](https://github.com/guillermocalvo/admob-unity-plugin).

Там все уже готово, практически. Остается только покрутить настройки.
Скачиваем пакет. В нем есть прифаб `AdMobPlugin`, кидаем его на сцену. Видим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `publisher id` вбиваем свой идентификатор. Всё.

HappyEnd!

---

Для теста включаем галочку `isTesting`. На продакшне - отключаем.
С настройками можно поиграться.

`AdMobPluginDebug` - нужен просто чтоб поиграться с настройками (где будет располагаться баннер и прочее), потыкав кнопочки на экране. Они как раз на скриншоте сверху изображены. На продакшне этот компонент естественно надо будет отключить, чтоб на экране этих кнопок не было))

`AdMobPluginMockup` - можно было прямо в редакторе посмотреть как выглядит баннер и видеть его непосредственно (на скриншоте он внизу по центру). Также этот компонент, чтоб было удобно разместить все где нужно и на продакшне отключить...

Как итог: `AdMobPluginDebug` и `AdMobPluginMockup` - только для эдитора, и для удобства визуального - как все будет выглядеть. Отключить на проде.

[Видео инстракшн](https://youtu.be/XbjsoK0IJpQ)

Comment: я крайне вам благодарен за труды, но я, вообщем и целом так и делал сначала. Проблема то вот в чем - не идет ничего! Поэтому и пустился на всякие ухищрения с объединением методов. Даже специально создал новенький, чистый проект, импортировал туда этот плагин с гугла официальный, сделал по вашему - но толку нет. Вообще. Проект компилируется но реклама не выводится, хотя условия простые - просто UI кнопку нажать для GameOver. Вообщем код и несколько картинок. Обратите внимание на предупреждения на картинках, в нижней строке Unity. Может в них дело.

Comment: @Dmitrii какие предупреждения?

Comment: не пускает опубликовать все в комментарии, слишком много. Сейчас главный пост отредактирую, посмотрите через минутку

Comment: @Dmitrii а плагин не ставили? это же проще

Comment: Мне нужна межстраничная реклама. Её нет в том плагине, он обновлялся 2 года назад.